# Split one list into two dimensional lists according to the specific number of elements in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to create two dimensional list from the one dimensional list. I created this list.

```
N_rp = {1:5, 2:5, 3:7, 4:3}
x_irp = []

for i in range(1,2):
    for r in range(1,2):
        for p in range(1,5):
            for pp in range(p, p+N_rp[p]):
                b = 'x{}_{}_{}'.format(i, r, pp)
                x_irp.append(b)
print(x_irp)
```

My output is:

```
['x1_1_1', 'x1_1_2', 'x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_2', 'x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6', 'x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6', 'x1_1_7', 'x1_1_8', 'x1_1_9', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6']
```

What i could not figure out is;

split this list into number of ''len(N_rp)'' so it is 4 in this example.

and

in each list there should be N_rp elements. In first list there should be first 5 elements. In second list there should be next 5. In third list, there should be next 7 elements, so on.

So my required output is:

```
[['x1_1_1', 'x1_1_2', 'x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5'], 
['x1_1_2', 'x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6'], 
['x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6', 'x1_1_7', 'x1_1_8', 'x1_1_9'], 
['x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6']]
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
N_rp = {1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 3}
x_irp = []

for i in range(1, 2):
    for r in range(1, 2):
        for start, end in N_rp.items():
            level = []
            for p in range(start, start + end):
                level.append(f"x{i}_{r}_{p}")
            x_irp.append(level)

print(x_irp)
```

**Output:**

```
[['x1_1_1', 'x1_1_2', 'x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5'],
['x1_1_2', 'x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6'],
['x1_1_3', 'x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6', 'x1_1_7', 'x1_1_8', 'x1_1_9'],
['x1_1_4', 'x1_1_5', 'x1_1_6']]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I shorten my real list. In my real list there are 212 'i', 10 'r' and 219 'p'

Comment: Ok changed back to include the `i` and `r`.

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked. And also can I join each list of elements with ' + ' ?

Comment: Like that ['x1_1_1' + 'x1_1_2' + 'x1_1_3' + 'x1_1_4' + 'x1_1_5']

Comment: @HarunHorasanlı Use `x_irp.append('+'.join(level))` instead of `x_irp.append(level)` for the output: `['x1_1_1+x1_1_2+x1_1_3+x1_1_4+x1_1_5', 'x1_1_2+x1_1_3+x1_1_4+x1_1_5+x1_1_6', 'x1_1_3+x1_1_4+x1_1_5+x1_1_6+x1_1_7+x1_1_8+x1_1_9', 'x1_1_4+x1_1_5+x1_1_6']` from your example.